# How do I change JTable title cell color in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jtableheader

I tried to change JTable title cells colour in NetBeans but it doesn't change. But trying to do same things in text editor and it is running perfectly .

This is the Java code related to my problem:

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show your `main()` method. Maybe you are using some look and feel.

Comment: I'm trying this in netbeans initComponents() method. not in main() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Netbeans gives a set up look and feel. You can create custom renderer though like this

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

    jTable1.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            l.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));

            l.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            return l;
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Also made with GUI Builder

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `netbeans`  then there will be a line in your `main()` method.
`UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");`

Comment this line and then see the result.

Comment: your answer is correct. but after doing this, window looks becomes a windows classic look. it's ok. thanks.